# Hide elements when click outside of triggering element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div `.post-control` with an onClick event. After clicking, an inner div `.post-control-popover` appears. After a second click, the inner div disappears. The code I am using :

```
$('.post-control').click(function(e){

        $(this).toggleClass("active");

    var bool = $('.post-control').hasClass('active');    

             if(bool)
        {
                    $('.post-control-popover').show();
        }
        else
        {
                    $('.post-control-popover').hide();
        }


     e.preventDefault();      
 });
```

What should I add to this code so that, an onClick outside the outer div will make the inner div disappear.

Comment: Thank you all for your time and suggestions. Solution found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a single event for the whole document that closes your `.post-control-popover`

```
$('.post-control').click(function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    var bool = $('.post-control').hasClass('active');    

    if(bool)
    {
        $('.post-control-popover').show();
        $(document).one('click', function() {
            $('.post-control-popover').hide();
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $('.post-control-popover').hide();
    }

    e.preventDefault();      
});
```

`one` method binds a listener to an event and destroys it after one fire.

Comment: I found the solution, I will accept yours even if I didnt try it. and I will add my solution as an edit to yours, please to accept my edit.

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces If you found your own solution, post your own answer.

Comment: Okey, thank you anyway for your time. I understook your approach. +1

Comment: Your edit was already rejected but I would do so anyway. Your answer supposed that the `click` event for `document` is binded all the time. Mine fires only if the popover is appearing. @whitelettersandblankspaces please, consider my answer again - you might not want to fire the event on every click wherever inside the `document`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var $pc = $('.post-control'),
    $pcp = $('.post-control-popover');
$pc.click(function (e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $pcp.toggle($(this).hasClass('active'));

    $(document).one('click', function () {
        $pc.removeClass("active");
        $pcp.hide()
    })

    return false;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nX7zk/)

Comment: I'd make the document click just `once` and add it during the click event.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.post-control').click(function(e){
    $('.post-control-popover').show();
}); 

$('body').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.currentTarget.class != 'post-control-popover') {
        $('.post-control-popover').hide();
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it easily in a more simple way.

```
$('.post-control').click(function(e){
    $('.post-control-popover').toggleClass('disable');
});
```

you now just have to add to your css a class called 'disable' and give it either display:none, opacity:0 or visibility: hidden.

greetings Timotheus

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```
 $('.post-control').click(function(e){



        $(this).toggleClass("active");

    var if_post_control_active = $('.post-control').hasClass('active');  
        if(if_post_control_active)
        {
                    $('.post-control-popover').show();

 $(document).click(function() {
  $('.post-control-popover').hide();
});
        }
        else
        {
                    $('.post-control-popover').hide();
        }


     e.preventDefault();  
     e.stopPropagation();
 });
```